# travis setup heroku command yields repository not known error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, travis-ci

I am working through the [Raild 4 In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/rails-4-in-action) book.  On Chapter 13: Deployment, page 464 it is having you do the final configuration for a deployment hook for `travis` to push to your heroku app upon passing specs.

The book already had me do the following:

- I entered the `.travis.yml` file in the root of my app.
- I then went to `https://travis-ci.org/` and signed in via my Github account.
- I then flipped the switch to on for my project.
- Now when I do a `git push` I notice on `travis` that it does a build and it runs all my specs.  It looks like it all passes.  At the bottom it says `Done. Your build exited with 0.`

Ok now the deployment hook with heroku.

- I do `gem install travis` to get the gem onto my computer
- I then do `travis login` with a github token and it says: `Successfully Logged in!`

Now I run `travis setup heroku` and here is the error:

```
repository not known to https://api.travis-ci.org/:my_repo_name/my_app_name
```

The book does not mention this error message.  I attempted looking around and couldn't find anyone who had run into this problem.

How can I get the `travis setup heroku` command to do what it is supposed to do?

**Update**

The issue is that my repo's name on Github is `Ticketee` and travis-ci for some reason thought it was `ticketee`.  The answer was to open up the following file from the root of my app:

```
vim .git/config
```

At the bottom I saw the following

```
[travis]
    slug = my_git_user_name/ticketee
```

and I had to change it to this:

```
[travis]
    slug = my_git_user_name/Ticketee
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're having a similar issue as described in this [travis ci issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2334)

To solve this issue, add the following in your `.git/config` file:

```
[travis]
    slug = <user/org>/<repo>
```

make sure `slug` matches the case-sensitive URL structure you see in Travis.

Comment: I'm having trouble here.  I do not have a .git/config file.

Comment: do you mean put it in my .travis.yml file?  I attempted doing that and put it in and it didn't work. Maybe I'm not putting it in correct?

Comment: I attempted creating a `.git/config` file which didn't quite make sense to me.  It changed the file name into `.git:config` and unfortunately it did not take the error away.

Comment: I also attempted creating a file at config/.git and put that in and it did not work.

Comment: yes! got it! I didn't realize there was a hidden .git file in my app.