# Rails App on Heroku: Where is my Encrypted API key For Travis CI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I need to grab my encrypted API Key.

On `https://dashboard.heroku.com/account` I notice the section for **API Key**.  Is that what this is referring to?  I'm not sure if this is actually the **encrypted** key or if the encrypted key is actually somewhere else.

There is nothing that states this is the *encrypted* key.  It just says "API Key".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add travis CI api key to your `.travis.yml` file.

From the [travis ci documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku/)

If you have both the Heroku and Travis CI command line clients installed, you can get your key, encrypt it and add it to your `.travis.yml` by running the following command from your project directory:

`travis encrypt $(heroku auth:token) --add deploy.api_key`

You can also use the Travis CI command line setup tool:

`travis setup heroku`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  When I do that here is the error message I get: `repository not known to https://api.travis-ci.org/:my_repo_name/my_app_name`.  I think the issue is that the name of my app is capitalized on github: Foobar, but the name of my app is lowercased: foobar.  Any tips?

Comment: please see my question here if you do not mind.  It might provide some more tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711472/travis-setup-heroku-command-yields-repository-not-known-error

Comment: Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2334
and make sure `slug` matches the case-sensitive URL structure you see in Travis.